# How to generate a star Triangle pattern using Java

Tags: java

How to print a star triangle pattern using java. Pattern is something like this

```
            * ====> row 1
           * *
          *   *
         *     *
        * * * * *
```

it can be n number of rows and from second row onwards there is odd number of white spaces between 2 stars like, 1,3,5, and last row have all the stars each separated by one white space.

Below is the Code I was working on to print the triangle?

```
public class Triangle
 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int row = 4;
    int space =0;
    System.out.println("*");
    for (int i=1;i<row;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
        for(space=0;space<i;space = space+i)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
    }


enter code here
    for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
}
```

}

How do I proceed?

Comment: If you show us how you started, we can tell you how to proceed.

Comment: I was able to achieve below using help from stack overflow,

public class Triangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i=1; i<10; i += 2)
        {
            for (int k=0; k < (4 - i / 2); k++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}

       *
     ***
   *****
 *******
*********

Comment: what have you tried so far? you noticed there is a pattern that you could follow, so where is the exact problem. I suggest reading [reading how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Show the code you used to print the pattern

Comment: Basically i was able to print the complete triangle

Comment: Below is the code, which i was working on,

public class Triangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int row = 4;
        int space =0;
        System.out.println("*");
        for (int i=1;i<row;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            for(space=0;space<i;space = space+i)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
        }
        //System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
    }
}

Comment: Edit the question to include the code

Comment: There’s still no question or error description.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Triangle {

    public static void DrawWithStars(int dimension)
    {
        if(dimension < 0)
        {
            //Assuming that a triangle with dimension = 0 is a dot....
            System.out.println("No valid dimension");
        }
        else
        {
            //To print the first dimension - 1 rows
            for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dimension - i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                //Print the dot of the row 1 at the end
                if(i != 0)
                    System.out.print("*");

                for (int j = 0; j < 2 * i - 1; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                System.out.println("*");
            }

            //To print the last row

            for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }

            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package apple;

public class Triangle
{
public static void main(String...strings){
    int midspace = -1;
    int row = 4;
    String star = "";
    for(int y=row-1; y>0; y--){ 
        for(int space = 1;space <= y ; space++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("*");

        for(int i = midspace; i>0; i--)
            System.out.print(" ");
        midspace += 2;

        star = (y!=row-1) ? "*":"";
        System.out.println(star);

    }


    for(int y=((row*2)-1); y>0; y--){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}

}
```